# Use Querystring to Set Selection in Dropdown List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms

Full disclosure: I'm very new to .NET and sort of feeling my way through it.  Been asked to make a tweak and I'm not sure exactly where to start.  Was hoping someone might be able to provide a helpful link or example.  Would be greatly appreciated.

Basically, I'd like to read in a querystring... let's call it "inquirytype".  If that querystring is equal to "other", I want to change the selection in a dropdown box that I have in my .ascx control (see below):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="inquiry_type" runat="server" CssClass="inquiry_type">
   <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True">Select Below</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Place an Order</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Order Status</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Is there a way I can keep this code in my .ascx file and still achieve this by adding something to my .cs file?  Or must I create a function in my .cs that creates this dropdown list altogether?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["foo"];
```

You can also do it like this:

```
ListItem item = DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(Request.QueryString["foo"]);
if (item != null)
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
```

I don't think you'll need to test for null, but incase you do:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["foo"] ?? String.Empty;
```

Comment: Oh wow, that works like a champ!  Thanks!  Next question:  I have some javascript linked to that drop down list.  When it changes, I have two additional form fields that are displayed.  If I use this code, those boxes do not appear.  What would be the best way to fire that script so that they do?

Comment: So you have some JavaScript that displays fields when the selection changes?

Comment: That's correct.  It's called "inquiry_type_onchange"... it reads in the zero-indexed option that is selected and then displays boxes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

if (Drodownlist.Text == "")
            {

```
     //here  fill if is empty
     //lleno si esta vacio


        }
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation and use code format to represent code selecting the code and pressing cntrl+k